# Python: fast subsetting and looping dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, numpy, pandas

I have the folowing minimal code which is too slow. For the 1000 rows I need, it takes about 2 min. I need it to run faster.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(1000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
start_algorithm = time.time()
myunique = df['D'].unique()
for i in myunique:
    itemp = df[df['D'] == i]
    for j in myunique:
        jtemp = df[df['D'] == j]
```

I know that numpy can make it run much faster but keep in mind that I want to keep a part of the original dataframe (or array in numpy) for specific values of column 'D'. How can I improve its performance?

Comment: Try always to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions. In case of _pandas_ questions please provide sample _input_ and _output_ data sets (5-7 rows in CSV/dict/JSON/Python code format _as text_, so one could use it when coding an answer for you). This will help to avoid _situations_ like: `your code isn't working for me` or `it doesn't work with my data`, etc.

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to do ...

Comment: I don't want a simple loop through rows of dataframe. Otherwise I could easily implement it in numpy. I need the loop to be through unique values of olumn 'D' which will produce subsets of the original dataframe. With numpy I should iterate through all elements of a 2d array and store the rows with the same value in column 'D'  . There is no real data to work upon and that is why I gave random values to the dataframe.

Comment: What's the difference between `itemp` and `jtemp`? Again as MaxU said, a sample representative input data and the expected output with the explanation as to how it was achieved, would help a lot.

Comment: It's still not clear what are you trying to do! You have nested loops which are not connected anyhow - why do you need them? Are you 100% sure that you need loops at all? If i run your code i get the same row from `df` two times - in `itemp` and in `jtemp`. So it's hardly possible to help you without clear understanding what are you after

Comment: It's not the result that concerns me but the whole sequence. I can easily replace itemp and jtemp with a=1 or print "Hello" so ignore that.

Comment: Then it's easy to answer your question - if you want to speed up your code, get rid of loops. It's a general answer for your general question... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid computing the sub-DataFrame `df[df['D'] == i]` more than once. The original code computes this `len(myunique)**2` times. Instead you can compute this once for each `i` (that is, `len(myunique)` times in total), store the results, and then pair them together later. For example,

```
    groups = [grp for di, grp in df.groupby('D')]
    for itemp, jtemp in IT.product(groups, repeat=2):
        pass
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools as IT
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(1000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

def using_orig():
    myunique = df['D'].unique()
    for i in myunique:
        itemp = df[df['D'] == i]
        for j in myunique:
            jtemp = df[df['D'] == j]

def using_groupby():
    groups = [grp for di, grp in df.groupby('D')]
    for itemp, jtemp in IT.product(groups, repeat=2):
        pass
```

---

```
In [28]: %timeit using_groupby()
10 loops, best of 3: 63.8 ms per loop
In [31]: %timeit using_orig()
1 loop, best of 3: 2min 22s per loop
```

---

Regarding the comment:

> I can easily replace itemp and jtemp with a=1 or print "Hello" so ignore that

The answer above addresses how to compute `itemp` and `jtemp` more efficiently. If `itemp` and `jtemp` are not central to your real calculation, then we would need to better understand *what you really want to compute* in order to suggest (if possible) a way to compute it faster.

Comment: My comment about itemp and jtemp was meant to emphasize that (as I thought at the time) the problem was with unique. As I can now see from the amazing answer of unutbu, I was clearly wrong and I apologize to the fellow members of stackoverflow for somewhat misguiding them. Your answer works fine and I thank you all for your time and contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized approach to form the groups based on unique elements from `"D"` column -

```
# Sort the dataframe based on the sorted indices of column 'D'
df_sorted = df.iloc[df['D'].argsort()]

# In the sorted dataframe's 'D' column find the shift/cut indces 
# (places where elements change values, indicating change of groups). 
# Cut the dataframe at those indices for the final groups with NumPy Split.
cut_idx = np.where(np.diff(df_sorted['D'])>0)[0]+1
df_split = np.split(df_sorted,cut_idx)
```

**Sample testing**

1] Form a sample dataframe with random elements :

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
>>> df
    A   B   C   D
0  68  68  90  39
1  53  99  20  85
2  64  76  21  19
3  90  91  32  36
4  24   9  89  19
```

2] Run the original code and print the results :

```
>>> myunique = df['D'].unique()
>>> for i in myunique:
...     itemp = df[df['D'] == i]
...     print itemp
... 
    A   B   C   D
0  68  68  90  39
    A   B   C   D
1  53  99  20  85
    A   B   C   D
2  64  76  21  19
4  24   9  89  19
    A   B   C   D
3  90  91  32  36
```

3] Run the proposed code and print the results :

```
>>> df_sorted = df.iloc[df['D'].argsort()]
>>> cut_idx = np.where(np.diff(df_sorted['D'])>0)[0]+1
>>> df_split = np.split(df_sorted,cut_idx)
>>> for split in df_split:
...     print split
... 
    A   B   C   D
2  64  76  21  19
4  24   9  89  19
    A   B   C   D
3  90  91  32  36
    A   B   C   D
0  68  68  90  39
    A   B   C   D
1  53  99  20  85
```